# JPA many-to-many duplicate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, many-to-many

I have tables Tags, Blog and BlogTags.
With using many-to-many I would like a blog to have many tags (as objects with id, name).

In front end, when I add tags, they are created with name only and id of null so when I save the blog, new tag gets created every time as it auto increments Tag, what I would like is for the Tag to be merged with blog if said tag already exists. The idea is so that I can click on any give tag and get the all the blogs associated with it.

So object sent to backend would be:

```
{id: null,
name: 'name'
,.....
tags: [{id: null, name: 'name},{id: null, name: 'name}]}
```

Any help is appreciated.

```
@Data
@Entity
public class Tag {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String name;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "tags", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.MERGE)
    private List<BlogPost> blogPosts;
}
```

```
public class BlogPost {

//other data

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.PERSIST})
    @JoinTable(
            name = "blog_post_tag",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "blog_post_id")},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")})
    private List<Tag> tags;
}
```

Comment: It's not automatically done check in database existance and then save new one

Answer (score 0):

I went with @ElementCollection without many-to-many annotations and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Not having the TAG ID is the normal behavior to register.

You can try, which for me is the best option, to load a master table from which you get the id if it already exists and with a find (depending on the technology used) at the moment the user inserts the check if tag. exists to load the id, get the DB entity and set the relationship of the tag entity to the post

Or before saving the entity, post iterate over all the tags making a query by tag to see if it exists and assign it.

In essence it is the same but with the first option we only make a query to DB